# What tools to use to model charge migration?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, biophysics, ions

I would like to simulate charge migration in an applied electrical field in the context of a biological system.  Some of the charges are ions floating in solution (which cannot cross the cell membrane, so they form an electrical double layer at the membrane).  Some of the charges are tethered (fixed charges on a macromolecule).  The problem can probably be simplified to a 1D model, with layers consisting of cell interior, membrane, tethered charges, cell exterior (where the electrical field is perpendicular to the membrane).  I would like to simulate the transmembrane voltage and the forces on the tethered charges in the time domain in response to specific applied external fields.

What is a good tool to simulate this kind of system?

Comment: With the recent resurgence of interest in drift-chambers in general and liquid-noble-gas time-projection-chambers in particular may mean that work on similar models is being done in various particle physics collaboration. Getting access to the code may be an issue, however, as well as heavy dependence of ROOT or Geant in the current form.